# Is it possible to monitor each cell memory for a specific process

Tags: linux, test, testing

Saying that I have a very simple C program `test.c`, which just prints "hello world", its name is `a.out` coming from `gcc test.c`.

I'm thinking if it's possible to monitor exactly what happened while running the `a.out`. For example, I want to know exactly how many bytes are used for `a.out`, what is happening in each cell memory (8-bit) used by `a.out` etc.

Well, I just want to get a stuff like this:
at this moment, the memory of address 0X00001234 is storing 00001001;
at the next moment, the memory of address 0X00001236 is putting its value to cache...

It sounds like using GDB to execute step by step. But for me, I have only an executable binary. I need a way to test it, instead of debugging.

Comment: `perf mem` maybe, or `rr`, or a recording emulator (QEMU in tracing mode)... (Just passing by, if no one else gets rounds to it I’ll write something up in more detail later.)

Comment: @Yves, you might like this one too https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419697/why-are-true-and-false-so-large/419704#419704

Comment: @StephenKitt What is `rr`?

Comment: @Rui, see [the `rr` web site](http://rr-project.org/) — available as `rr` in Debian & co. (Guess who packages it...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile the program with debugging info included using the `-g` option. `gdb` will follow then the source code, and when running step-by-step with display the proper lines from the source code if the corresponding source .c file(s) are present.

The `gdb`interface will also allow you to inspect the corresponding memory position of variables present on the source code.

I also would not use `test` for a binary name as it conflicts with pre-existing directives.

```
gcc -g mytest.c -o mytest
```

> -g tells the compiler to store symbol table information in the executable. Among other things, this includes:
>
> - symbol names
> - type info for symbols
> - files and line numbers where the symbols came from

see [How Does The Debugging Option -g Change the Binary Executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89603/how-does-the-debugging-option-g-change-the-binary-executable)

see also my related answer [Understanding what a Linux binary is doing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418354/understanding-what-a-linux-binary-is-doing/418357)

Comment: I'm reading your wonderful answer. In fact I'm a tester for Linux. Normally what I get is just a binary file. I think the binary file that I get is compiled without `-g`.

Comment: How come tester?

Comment: Well, I'm testing the performance of system while executing some executable binary file. Normally I use some commands and tools to do so such as `perf`. Today I'm thinking if I can test deeper than these tools... This is why I post this question.

Comment: Google `Amazon, Systems Performance: Enterprise and the Cloud, Brendan Gregg`. This last comment is less confusing than your question. Brendan Dtrace book is also a related good read, but sadly dtrace in Linux is a pain on the neck.